# C# How would you create a class that can be either an int a null or an array of the same class I just describe?

Tags: c#, class, oop, data-structures

this is a design problem that I couldn't imagine any elegant solution for, how would you create the described class so, as an example of utilization, when instantiated you could call a print function, and if it is an int just print the number, if its null then won't do anything and if its an array then print ith (inner iterator I guess) element of such array of the array. Here goes nothing, Thanks in advance!

Thanks all for the proposed answers, to be more specific of the requirement.

having an example: `[[1,2,3], null, 4, 5, [6,null,7]]` where all the elements in here are of type `MyIntOrArray` including the main array itself, so when calling to the print 7 times, you will have an output such as "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"

In any case I'm not that interested in the `Print` functionality but more interested in the implementation/structure/class on how to create such requirement.

```
public class MyIntOrArray
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
    public MyIntOrArray[] Values { get; set; }
    private bool AmIArray { get; set; }
    private int InnerIndex { get; set; }

    public MyIntOrArray(int? value)
    {
        Value = value;
        AmIArray = false;
    }

    public MyIntOrArray(int size, bool isArray)
    {
        Values = new MyIntOrArray[size];
        AmIArray = true;
    }

    public bool Print()
    {
        if(AmIArray)
        {
            if (InnerIndex < Values.Length)
            {
                if (Values[InnerIndex].Print())
                    InnerIndex += 1;

                return InnerIndex >= Values.Length ? true : false;
            }                
        }
        else if(Value != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Value.ToString());                
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a recursive data structure? I think you are close to what you want, but it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was an FAANG interview question asked to me a couple years ago and I never forgot it, I did my research, but I couldn't find anything like it  anywhere It is my desire to poke the minds of the more experienced and creative peers to try to find an idea that I'm not able to see.

Comment: If a `MyIntOrArray` (`A`) includes another `MyIntOrArray` (`B`), and they are both array. `B` has two elements, and `B` has already `Print()` once before `A` is instantiated, so `B`'s current index is at 2nd element. When calling `A.Print()`, should it print 2nd element of `B`, or start from 1st element of `B`?

Comment: TY for the reply, I would say printing the 2nd element of `MyIntOrArray (B)`, since object inner state shouldn't be modified, in any case functionality is not my main concern but the class/structure architecture.

Comment: If I have something like this `var myIntOrArray = new MyIntOrArray(new[] { new MyIntOrArray(5), new MyIntOrArray(6) });
myIntOrArray.Print();`, would you expect the output to be `5 6`? I'm not sure about the `InnerIndex` requirement

Comment: This feels like `LinkedList` can be put to use, but I suggest using `Queue` first to keep things simple. The `public MyIntOrArray(int size, bool isArray)` doesn't follow requirement if I understand correct, as it should be a constructor with `MyIntOrArray[]?` as argument.

Comment: @JohanP TY for the reply, since you're creating an array with two `MyIntOrArray` integers type, `InnerIndex` of `myIntOrArray` variable would start at 0 meaning would print the first element in the array, so in this case would print `5`, if instead of a `5` it is an array `(AA)`, then it would print the element in the `InnerIndex` position that belongs to that nested `(AA)` array.

Comment: Why not just an array of `int?` and a `bool`. If the bool is true, then the object represents a scalar value (whose value is held in the zero index). If false, it's a full on array. Implement an indexer to handle indexing into the array (throwing if the object is scalar). Remember, you can encapsulate an implementation that looks very different from the public signature

Comment: Do you really want it recursively defined, or do you want "able to represent a nullable int or an array of nullable int"?  I can almost see a purpose in what I described in the previous comment.  A recursively defined data structure like what you title describes can melt brains if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most answers here seem to miss the exotic requirement that if the contents is an array, the `Print` method should print one value and advance an internal pointer. I'll deal with that requirement below.

The OP, however, doesn't specify what should happen if you call `Print` enough times to exhaust the array. I'll be assuming that in this case, the method should print nothing more, but another option is to wrap around and start again from the beginning.

I'm going to give a specialised and a generalisable answer.

## Specialised implementation

Given the requirements, you can take advantage of arrays including the two other alternatives as special cases: Null (or nothing) is the empty array, and *value* is a singleton (one-element) array.

Thus, a specialised implementation could look like this:

```
public sealed class IntOrArrayOrNothing
{
    private readonly int[] ints;
    private int idx;

    public IntOrArrayOrNothing()
    {
        ints = Array.Empty<int>();
    }

    public IntOrArrayOrNothing(int i)
    {
        ints = new[] { i };
        idx = -1; // Sentinel value
    }

    public IntOrArrayOrNothing(int[] ints)
    {
        this.ints = ints;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        if (ints.Length == 0 || ints.Length <= idx)
            return;

        if (idx == -1) // Check sentinel value indicating a single int
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ints[0]);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ints[idx++]);
    }
}
```

A fair criticism of this specialised implementation is that it isn't easily changed or extended. What if you want to wrap the index around back to zero if you reach the end? What if you want to print the array in one go? What if you want to do something else than printing?

## Generalisable design

As a general rule, whenever you run into a requirement where a type should be one of *mutually exclusive* alternatives, you need a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Some languages support those natively. In [F#](https://fsharp.org), for example, you'd just declare the type like this:

```
type IntOrArrayOrNothing = Nothing | Int of int | Array of int array
```

Perhaps, however, the actual type of value (here, `int`) doesn't matter, in which case you could make the type generic (or, *parametrically polymorphic*):

```
type ValueOrCollectionOrNothing<'a> = Nothing | Value of 'a | Collection of 'a seq
```

Unfortunately, a language like C# doesn't support sum types out of the box, but not all is lost. You can implement your own sum types in one of (at least) two different ways:

- [Church encoding](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/22/church-encoding)
- [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

[These alternatives are actually isomorphic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type). Church encoding is more concise, but since this question is tagged *oop*, I'll show the Visitor implementation instead.

There's really no need to go to these lengths in this particular case, since even with generics, the *nothing* and the *value* cases can be implemented using a collection. Still, I'll proceed in order to demonstrate how the general technique discussed in the linked articles apply to a concrete case.

I'll also implement the code as immutable values instead, since mutable state in general just makes it more difficult to reason about code.

So, first, declare a class:

```
public sealed class ValueOrCollectionOrNothing<T>
{
    private readonly IValueOrCollectionOrNothing imp;

    public ValueOrCollectionOrNothing()
    {
        imp = new Nothing();
    }

    public ValueOrCollectionOrNothing(T value)
    {
        imp = new Value(value);
    }

    public ValueOrCollectionOrNothing(IReadOnlyCollection<T> values)
    {
        imp = new Collection(values);
    }

    public TResult Accept<TResult>(
        IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult> visitor)
    {
        return imp.Accept(visitor);
    }

    private interface IValueOrCollectionOrNothing
    {
        TResult Accept<TResult>(
            IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult> visitor);
    }

    // Implementation classes (see below) go here...
}
```

Notice that the three constructor overloads initialise three different implementations of the `IValueOrCollectionOrNothing` interface (see below).

The `IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor` interface is where you actually 'enumerate' the mutually exclusive cases:

```
public interface IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult>
{
    TResult VisitNothing();
    TResult VisitValue(T value);
    TResult VisitCollection(IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection);
}
```

The `Accept` method takes a visitor, and just delegates to `imp.Accept`.

The `Nothing` class is a nested class:

```
private sealed class Nothing : IValueOrCollectionOrNothing
{
    public TResult Accept<TResult>(
        IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitNothing();
    }
}
```

The same goes for `Value`:

```
private sealed class Value : IValueOrCollectionOrNothing
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Value(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TResult Accept<TResult>(
        IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitValue(value);
    }
}
```

and `Collection`:

```
private sealed class Collection : IValueOrCollectionOrNothing
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection;

    public Collection(IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public TResult Accept<TResult>(
        IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<T, TResult> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitCollection(collection);
    }
}
```

What might a Visitor look like?

If you wanted to print the entire collection, you *could* do something like this:

```
public sealed class PrintVisitor : IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<int, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public IEnumerable<string> VisitNothing()
    {
        return Array.Empty<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> VisitValue(int value)
    {
        return new[] { value.ToString() };
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> VisitCollection(IReadOnlyCollection<int> collection)
    {
        return collection.Take(1).Select(i => i.ToString());
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to advance a collection index, you might instead do this:

```
public sealed class PrintAndChangeStateVisitor
    : IValueOrCollectionOrNothingVisitor<int, (IReadOnlyCollection<string>, PrintAndChangeStateVisitor)>
{
    private readonly int idx;

    public PrintAndChangeStateVisitor() : this(0)
    {
    }

    private PrintAndChangeStateVisitor(int idx)
    {
        this.idx = idx;
    }

    public (IReadOnlyCollection<string>, PrintAndChangeStateVisitor) VisitNothing()
    {
        return (Array.Empty<string>(), this);
    }

    public (IReadOnlyCollection<string>, PrintAndChangeStateVisitor) VisitValue(
        int value)
    {
        return (new[] { value.ToString() }, this);
    }

    public (IReadOnlyCollection<string>, PrintAndChangeStateVisitor) VisitCollection(
        IReadOnlyCollection<int> collection)
    {
        if (collection.Count <= idx)
            return (Array.Empty<string>(), this);

        return (
            new[] { collection.ElementAt(idx).ToString() },
            new PrintAndChangeStateVisitor(idx + 1));
    }
}
```

Notice that this doesn't require you to change the `ValueOrCollectionOrNothing<T>` class; you just write another Visitor. Thus, a design like this is more extensible.

Comment: Do you have another reference for the requirements for this question? It wasn't clear to me what OP was asking - I didn't catch the part about advancing a pointer.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson It's implied by the OP: *"if its an array then print ith (inner iterator I guess) element of such array of the array"*, together with the proposed code.

Comment: I see. It is confusing to call that an array then, because arrays don't remember the last index they were given (that I know of). Perhaps what the problem is getting at is a tree data structure (graph search).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all of the details involved, something along these lines will do what you are asking for

```cs
public class MyIntOrArray
{
    private readonly MyIntOrArray[]? _array;
    private readonly int? _value;
    public MyIntOrArray(int? value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public MyIntOrArray(MyIntOrArray[]? array)
    {
        _array = array;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        if (_value is not null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        if (_array is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var myIntOrArray in _array)
        {
            myIntOrArray.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create primitive types from scratch. But you can extend all data-types using `extension methods`. In `C#` `object` is the root data-type and all `data-types` including `int`, `long`, `string`, `char`, ...., `struct`s, `class` are a kind of `object` you can simply work on `object` to extend whole data-types.

here is an example of `extension method`:

```
 public static class ObjectExtensions 
 {
      public static void Print(this object obj)
      {
          if (obj is null)
               Console.WriteLine("Null");

          if (obj is int integerValue)
               Console.WriteLine(integerValue);

          // Read below link if you want to support all kind of arrays:
          // First: you need to check whether if its an array or not `object.GetType().IsArray()` and next you can read below link to casting it to array of type `T`
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484948/c-sharp-convert-object-of-type-array-to-t-where-t-is-an-array
          else if (obj is int[] array)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    Console.Writeline(array[i]);
          }

          // For non-primitive types I recommend you to define an interface (e.g IPrintable) 
          // And using `Reflection check if implements `IPrintable` or not. If it does, you can cast it to `IPrintable` and call `Print` method from it.
      }
 }
```